# Unable to load csv file into networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a dataset with a headers and rows, in this format

```
login,project_name,ccount

kts,blocklist-ipsets,2192232
Ken,heartbeat,1477010
Code,feature-tests,584334
dat,mirage-ci-logs,584046
vip,committer,533839
RQHVMCAU,mirror,505976
ANHTMOTA,d43-en,378663
mikins,openapsdev,348992
direwolf-github,my-app,340046
```

where login, project_name and ccount are the headers
 how can i read this dataset into networkx graph and view the graph.ccount values are the weight of the edges. I am a newbie to python and networkx.

 this is what is have done already

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
def _get_graph_file():
   G = nx.DiGraph()
   git = csv.reader('file.csv')
   G.add_weighted_edges_from(git_df)
   return G
print(_get_graph_file())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the file object to the csv reader and not the file directly. Also the syntax for adding the nodes with edge weights is incorrect. You are not using the correct variable names.

Here is the code with the correct syntax and format:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv

def _get_graph_file():
   G = nx.DiGraph()

   #Read the csv file
   file_obj = open('file.csv')

   #Pass the file object to csv reader
   git = csv.reader(file_obj,delimiter=',')

   #Ignore the headers
   headers = git.next()

   #Ignore the line between headers and actual data
   git.next()

   #git is the variable to be passed, not git_df
   G.add_weighted_edges_from(git)

   return G

my_graph = _get_graph_file()

#To get the list of nodes
print my_graph.nodes()

#To get the list of edges
print my_graph.edges()

#To get the weight between two edges
print my_graph['Ken']['heartbeat']['weight']
```

Comment: git.next() works on only python 2.7 but not 3.x, tried working with next(git) but it still shows error. But the explanation has been helpful.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-1-35dbdab10081>", line 27
    print my_graph.nodes()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It shows the error on print statement. Since you are using python 3, change the syntax of print statement accordingly

Comment: Note that the weight here will be a string, which is probably not what you want - you'd need to parse the third column.

Comment: @MohammedKashif you have been greate

Comment: @chthonicdaemon how do i do the parsing

Comment: @josephnkoro I've shown how I would do it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas works a little more like you would want the CSV module to work, especially considering that you probably want to convert the ccount column to numbers. It also has built-in support for skipping that blank line at the start.

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
import pandas as pd

def _get_graph_file():
    G= nx.DiGraph()
    git = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=[1])
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(git.values)
    return G

G = _get_graph_file()
print(G['kts']['blocklist-ipsets'])
```

Output:

`{'weight': 2192232}`

Comment: didn't print any thing.

Comment: @josephnkoro I'm not sure what you expected to see from your print statement. I've changed to it allow you to see that the graph is constructed correctly.